# Seeking clarification on disputed flag

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

I raised a "not an answer" flag on [How do I practice arpeggios on the piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/65031/how-do-i-practice-arpeggios-on-the-piano/65052#65052), which was resolved as "disputed". No quarrel with the resolution, just looking to refine my participation on the site.

1. It would help to understand the mod's basis for the "dispute".

   My reasoning for the flag was that the post doesn't answer the question and rather expands on the poster's objections to various teaching methods. I hesitated in raising the flag due to the post's age (3 yrs).

   Was the "dispute" resolution based on

   - the age of the post (old and not egregious, so let it stand)
   - the content of the post (close enough to an answer)
   - something else?
2. For a case like this where I have some hesitation, is it generally better to flag first and ask questions later (as I chose to do), or is it better to meta first and flag later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your flag wasn't disputed by a ♦ moderator, it was disputed because the outcome of the [Low Quality Posts review](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/61329) was 'Looks OK'. You'd have to ask the individual reviewers why they reviewed the way they did.

General tendency on Stack Exchange sites is to leave those kind of answers alone. If it has been on the site for so long without causing problems, why not keep it?

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize I could look at the review history. That helps clarify that it this case it was just a difference of opinion on the quality of the post.